# WFP BackgroundWorker waits to other BackgroundWorker to finish

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

i have 2 BackgroundWorkers in my code.each one do some work and they cant run together that means that the second one need to wait for the first one to finish.i aslo dont want the application to crash when i am clickin the main window during work.how can i do it?

Comment: `i aslo dont want the application to crash when i am clickin the main window during work`... the only way is carefully test and debug the code.

Comment: You basically asking about [synchronization](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx), but if *they can't run together*, then why do you need two `BackgroundWorker`? Have one and supply it with parameter to select one of two jobs.

Comment: Why don't you use *Tasks*? Or *async/await* in case of C# 5? Both of these approaches are much easier and have built-in support for your scenario.

Comment: my application is developed in .NET 3.5...

Answer (score 2):

First thing is, maybe you can do all the background work in 1 `BackgroundWorker`.

To answer your question, you can start the 2nd `BackgroundWorker` in the 1st's [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.95).aspx) event handler.

```
bw1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw1_RunWorkerCompleted);

private void bw1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //celebration!

    //and then start the 2nd BackgroundWorker
    BackgroundWorker bw2 = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw2.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw2_DoWork);
    bw2.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw2_RunWorkerCompleted);
    bw2.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: i will test it... if i will use RunWorkerCompleted event it will be done in main thread...

Comment: yes, `RunWorkerCompleted` is run on the main thread. That is why `BackgroundWorker` was invented, some people don't realize they have to marshal to the main thread to update UI.